# Iniciar tomcat desde consola windows

Tags: tomcat

Tengo descaragado el tomcat 8 y puedo arrancaro sin problemas:

Abro una consola, me voy a la carpeta bin y ejecuto startup.bat, se empieza a iniciar tomcat pero si cierro esa consola el tomcat se detiene, como puedo hacer que este permanentemente y solo se detenga si paro el proceso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay dos formas en que puedes ejecutar *Tomcat 8* con el comportamiento que deseas.

### Service Windows Installer

Esta opción te permite instalar *[Tomcat 8](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi)* con un asistente que te guiará en la instalación del programa.

Tienes la opción de agregar que *Tomcat* se inicie como servicio de *Windows* así como elegir un nombre para identificar este servicio desde la ventana de **Servicios de Windows**.

### Zip

Si tomaste esta opción es requerido ir a la carpeta donde se descomprimiste *Tomcat 8*, por ejemplo `C:\Apache\apache-tomcat-8.5.34\bin`), desde una línea de comando y ejecutar lo siguiente:

```
service.bat install
```

Esto creará un servicio con el nombre `Tomcat8` lo cual te dará la posibilidad de utilizar la herramienta `tomcat8w.exe` ubicado en la misma carpeta de *Tomcat* donde podrás administrar el servicio.

Si necesitas más información para personalizar algún valor puedes consultar la página: [Windows service HOW-TO](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html#Installing_services)

Answer (score 0):

Prueba, en lugar de ejecutarlo con doble click, a lanzarlo desde linea de comandos con la opción `start`

```
catalina.bat start
```

Comment: realmente lo que hace es abrirme en otra consola, si cierro esa consola se apaga el tomcat, por ejemplo en ubuntu si lanzo el ./startup.sh sigue ejecutandose si cierro al consola

Comment: entonces usa el comando de windows para lanzar en background si no recuerdo mal era 
`start /b comando_a_ejectura`

Answer (score 0):

Edita el archivo .bat y escribe al final del código, la palabra `pause`, y te saldrá el mensaje:
`"Press any key to continue . . . "`.
Espero haber ayudado.